# Read a CSV file and put double quote on each item in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm really new to python and I have a simple question. I have a .csv file with the following content:

```
123,456,789
```

I want to read it and store it into a variable called "number" with the following format

```
"123","456","789"
```

So that when I do

```
print number
```

It will give the following output

```
"123","456","789"
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Update:
The following is my code:

```
input = csv.reader(open('inputfile.csv', 'r'))
for item in input:
    item = ['"' + item + '"' for item in item]
print item
```

It gave the following output:

```
['"123"', '"456"', '"789"']
```

Comment: You should post a little more about what you're trying to do. It seems like you should be using a list instead of a string to store the values, but without more context, it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

quotedData = StringIO()

with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(quotedData, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
       writer.writerow(row)
```

with `reader=csv.reader(StringIO('1,2,3'))` the output is:

```
print quotedData.getvalue()
"1","2","3"
```

Comment: How do you store the writer.writerow(row) into a variable?

Comment: You could just write to another `StringIO`-object

Answer (score 0):

If the whole file only contains numbers you can just open it as a regular file:

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        print ','.join('"{}"'.format(x) for x in line.rstrip().split(','))
```

It'd be better to append the lines to an array with append, tho. For example:

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    lines=[line.rstrip().split(',') for line in f]
```

There is a [CSV](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module there that might help you as well.

Comment: The OP said .csv file, not a .txt file.

Comment: This will give `123"456"789`, which isn't what the OP's after.

Comment: @Rapptz: A csv file is a Comma Separated File.
Probably the author meant something like: `','.join('"%s"' % tok for tok in line.split(','))`.
Anyway I'd use the `csv` module instead of splitting the lines directly.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Exactly, just typed on the way out, had no Python shell to try it out :) Thought it'd be obvious what I meant, but of course *someone* will always have to complain for tiny reasons. Geez!

Answer (score 0):

Using the csv-module, you can read the `.csv` file line-by-line and process each element from a tuple you gain. You can then just enclose each element into double-quotes.

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv"))
for line in reader:
    # line is a tuple ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
spamReader = csv.reader(open('eggs.csv', 'rb'))
for row in spamReader:
    this_row = ['"' + str(item) + '"' for item in row]
    print this_row
```

Comment: Usually if you have a `var = []` before a for-loop and a `var.append(...)` inside the loop, you should ask yourself if it could be written as a list comprehension.

Comment: @mgilson I've played with list comprehensions and love them as a language feature, but I haven't internalized them to the point where I use them when writing code. Good point about knowing when you're in a good situation to use them though, definitely somewhere my code (in general) could be  more pythonic. Edit made.

Comment: It took me a while to internalize list comprehensions -- and then it took a while after that to internalize generator expressions (e.g. `sum(x*x for x in myiter)` instead of `sum([x*x for x in myiter])` ).  But eventually after seeing it enough, it sticks (and then it's a very happy day).  One of my first projects that I took on to learn python was to write a subprocess based wrapper around gnuplot (the plotting utility).  I still use that wrapper all the time, but shudder when I think about how "unpythonic" a lot of that code is  ...

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv 
csvr = csv.reader(open(<yourfile.csv>,'r'))

def gimenumbers():
   for row in csvr:
     yield '","'.join(row)
```